# Depth of application state persistance

Tags: gui-design, android

Is it a good design pattern, in this case for Android, to persist the application state for wherever the user is, or should this be done just for the first level of depth?

Comment: What your app is about? It totally depends on what the application is. Mostly you should not save the state coz it can confuse the user. But since this question popped into your head, it might be good for your app!

Comment: @BlueFlame by saving the state I mean saving what screen the user is at if he closes the app/rotates the device. It is a shopping list app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its not good to save the state because the user can get confused easily. But for a shopping list app, it might be a good idea.

When I go out for shopping, I want to see my list quickly. I'm overwhelmed at the store and my hands are already busy picking things. I'd appreciate if the saved state can save me a button press or two.

Btw I can't imagine a deep hierarchy for a shopping list app. There could be categories of lists and that's all; even sub-categories would be too much in my opinion. I'd reckon you save the state. But do keep a button to go back to the top level.